# Received a letter from Toll Roads asking for Toll Due. Is that a scam?

Tags: usa, driving, california, tolls

Does anyone know anything about this? (I edited this so that whoever traveling to Orange County may find this useful)
I received a letter from thetollroads.com asking for $6.25 fee. And it warned me that if I wouldn't pay for it, I would have to pay $100 more after the deadline. 
Why would a non-government company in Orange County charge me? 
Is that a scam?

Comment: Are you certain the $6.25 fee is because of the parking ticket and not for driving on one of the many [toll roads](https://www.thetollroads.com/assets/objects/other/TR_Map.pdf) in Orange County?

Comment: OK I see. I did pass OC on the date it indicated. I've passed the deadline so I have to pay $100 more now. What should I do?

Comment: $6.25 is incredibly low for a parking violation. $100 is a much more likely value. However $6.25 is highly likely for a tool road fee.

Comment: You can look up the violation number at https://www.thetollroads.com/violation to see if it is a legitimate notice. If it works like other automated systems I'm familiar with, it should show the timestamp and plate number of the violation.

Comment: Thank you all. It turned out that I passed OC and travelled through some checkpoints that identified me as using a private lane without payment in advance. The name of that check point happened to be the name of avenue where I mistakenly parked, which is "catalina", so I intuitively linked the two events together. I guess the lesson is: when traveling through OC, watch out for TollRoads checkpoints. But seriously I didn't notice any signs of them. Anyone has more tips?

Comment: [This](https://goo.gl/maps/S784hFygpqs) seems rather hard to miss...

Comment: @JoErNanO Paying tolls incurred as a result of driving is very obviously travel related.

Comment: @djea3, I have a New York E-ZPass that works in 14 other states too, so that is possible, but I also have accounts for the Highway 407 toll road near Toronto and with California FasTrak  and I just don't see a big problem opening another account when you need it to pay a bill. With FasTrak you don't even need the transponder (though those are easy to get), you can pay based on license number. With that much driving it is hard to believe your daughter was unaware she was using toll roads, if she was unwilling to avoid them perhaps she should have proactively figured out how to pay for them?

Comment: I would say "theft of service" is when you take something you have no idea how to pay for, i.e. intentionally driving past plenty of signs that warn "Toll Road Entrance - No cash"... maybe hoping to get it free?   @dennis Get a FasTrak, it's free.  The retail price is credited back as stored value, and there are no maintenance fees to eat up your stored value, ahem EZpass!  You can even own one anonymously, but if you register your plate to your account, you don't even need the tag.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, this is legitimate. [The Toll Roads](https://www.thetollroads.com/) was [formed by the state of California](https://www.thetollroads.com/aboutus/toll-roads-history.php) to operate and maintain toll roads in Orange County.

When you entered one of the roads, you would have passed under an electronic sensor which reads FasTrak transponders from those who have them, and takes license plate pictures in order to bill those who do not. You also passed under such a sensor when you departed the toll road, and a sign which advised you to [visit thetollroads.com within five days](https://www.thetollroads.com/newsroom/pressreleases/archive/201501/pr-20150112-the-toll-roads-extends-online-payment-.php) to [pay the toll](https://www.thetollroads.com/violation/oneTimeToll.do?locale=en).

If you plan to drive that way again, you may wish to obtain a FasTrak (which is good for most California toll roads and bridges), or sign up for an ExpressAccount, which bills tolls to your credit card each day you drive, or on a prepaid basis, but only works for The Toll Roads. They're currently offering a [$10 in free tolls](https://www.thetollroads.com/communications/one-time-toll-promotion.php) promotion for signing up, which would cover your recent trip. Given where you live, though, you may find [Metro ExpressLanes](https://www.metro.net/projects/expresslanes/) (a FasTrak compatible system) more advantageous...